# Adding a number type item to an object inserted at top

Tags: javascript, object

I have a scenario that I'm not able to fix.

```
// Trying to achieve this object with same order:
// {name: 'Person', income: 1000, 2019: 34, 2018: 12};
data.forEach(item => {
    let obj = {
        name: item.name
    };
    Object.keys(item.summary).forEach(key => {
        obj['income'] = item.summary[key].income;
        item.summary[key].YearlySummary.forEach(yearSumm => {
            obj[yearSumm.year] = yearSumm.amount;
        });
    });
    console.log(obj); // {2019: 34, 2018: 12, income: 1000, name: Person};
});
```

What exactly is happening here is that when I am dynamically adding a property to an object, it does the sorting behind the scene. I don't want that and need to preserve the order in which items/property is added to an object.

Comment: I guess it is not possible

Comment: positive integers, who could be indices (32 bit) are sorted first as keys,

Comment: The javascript spec, as far as I know, does not actually require that object keys are sorted in order. You could, however, maintain a list of keys yourself with insert order.

Comment: Integer index properties, like `2018` and `2019` are retrieved by any relevant functions in ascending order, meaning the order of `2019` before `2018` is impossible.

Comment: You could alternatively use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to handle your object. Have a look on the article below.
https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/map-to-the-rescue-adding-order-to-object-properties/

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the order? There's almost always a better way to do it. If you need things in a specific order, use an array.

Comment: you can use treemap or somehow the array

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad mix between properties and arrays.

I dont understand your data structure. item seems to have only one item.summary. Why looping on the keys to erase, on each key, the income property of obj ?

I would have done :

```
data.forEach(item => {
    let obj = {
        name: item.name,
        income: item.summary.income,
        years = []            
    };
    Object.keys(item.summary).forEach(key => {
        item.summary[key].YearlySummary.forEach(yearSumm => {
            obj.years.push({ year : yearSumm.year, amount: yearSumm.amount});
        });
    });
});
```